# Is there a way to force Information updates in while training in ML agents Unity?

Tags: ml-agent

I Just found out how to train a ML agent in unity (after a lot of errors) and I saw the [INFO] tags pop up in my Command Prompt and give me a bunch of useful info about my agents (Total rewards, average rewards etc.) and this was useful but it was popping up every minute or so. Any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i found the answer:

to do it all you need to do is edit the .yaml file's attrabutes and decrease the checkpoint interval

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).